# How similar can a recreated logo be to the original without copyright infringement?

Tags: logo, copyright

I have a client that has a logo created by another company and only wants it tweaked a little for his own company. He just wants the type changed but wants to keep the exact same imagery and colors.

Can I run into a copyright issue by doing this?

One of the stipulations of the other graphic design company's logos are that they are all required to say "InterNACHI Certified" and he doesn't want this on the new logo. So it'd basically be recreating their logo, changing the font, and taking off the original creator's signature. This sounds kind of fishy to me and to be honest but I wanted a second opinion before I tell him I can't do it.

Comment: This is really a legal question. Ethically, it's bad. You *know* what you are being asked is inappropriate. I'd refuse the work..

Comment: ... and there is no such stipulation as "change is XXX amount and it's okay." That does not exist.

Comment: If it's a logo, no, you won't run into copyright issues. You'll run into patent/trademark issues. In either case, it's intellectual property law. If you feel you need to ask the question, then trust your gut. It's ethically wrong and legally risky. I'd ditch this client.